# GAE NDB how to fetch user data and put back into database

Tags: python, google-app-engine, database-design, app-engine-ndb

I recently switched from ext.db to NDB.model on Google App Engine and still fairly new to database in general.  Below is the new NDB code, which is mostly unchanged from ext.db.

What I want to do is when a user tries to login, check if uid exists.  If so, pass back the data from database as "entry."  If uid does not exist, then pull the data from Json and populate the new "entry."

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    uid             = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    firstName       = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    lastName        = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    emailAddress    = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    password        = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    created         = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add = True)
    last_modified   = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now = True)

    @classmethod
    def addUser(cls, info):
        entry = User.query().filter(Profile.uid == info['uid']).get        
        #USED TO BE FOR DB: entry = User.all().filter('uid = ', info['uid']).get()
        # if the profile doesn't exist, create it with basic information
        if entry == None:
            entry = User(uid = info["id"], 
                     firstName = info["firstName"], 
                     lastName = info["lastName"], 
                     emailAddress = info["emailAddress"], 
                     password = info[passwd])
        # At this point, we have a valid entry.
        entry.last_modified = datetime.now()
        entry.put()
        return entry
```

This code does NOT work.  I have tried `entry = User.query().filter(Profile.uid == info['uid']).get` but I get an attribute error

> AttributeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute 'last_modified'

I apologize for unable to clarify more, but am stuck.  What am I missing?  Everything worked fine with ext.db (note where I changed as noted in the code above), but I cannot see what is wrong with NDB.  I am seeking improvements as well, so please suggest changes.

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If was you I will use :

```
entry = User.query(Profile.uid == info['uid']).get()
```

Instead of :

```
entry = User.query().filter(Profile.uid == info['uid']).get
```

You can specify your filters directly inside query declaration separated by coma. Don't forget parenthesis at the end else you make a function pointer.

Answer (score 1):

This line is your problem

```
entry = User.query().filter(Profile.uid == info['uid']).get
```

You are not calling the method, just assigning it to entry.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the problem.  I am trying to understand it.  What is the difference between `entry = User.all().filter('uid = ', info['uid']).get()`, which worked with ext.db, and `entry = User.query().filter(Profile.uid == info['uid']).get` for NDB?

Comment: the line should be get() in both cases.   You just forgot the brakets, so you aren't calling get() in your code, you are just assigning the method to `entry` hence the error `AttributeError: 'instancemethod' object has no attribute 'last_modified'`  the instance method is get in this case.

Comment: and of course the instancemethod get has not attribute lastmodified.\

Answer (score 0):

```
@ndb.transactional
def my_get_or_insert(cls, id, **kwds):
  entry = cls.query().filter(Profile.uid == info['uid']).get  
  if not entry:
    entry = cls(**kwds)
  entry.last_modified = datetime.now()
  entry.put()
  return (entry, True)  # True meaning "created"
```

**Transactional -** to avoid dirty db operation

```
kwrds =  {'uid': info["id"], 
                     'firstName' : info["firstName"], 
                     'lastName' : info["lastName"], .....

}
```